# In linux window boarders are so ugly without border. How do we get them back?

Tags: gnome, gtk

Not only are they ugly, but they are far less functional ... having a wide boarder means it is far easier to resize on a laptop with a touch pad. No  drag needed, just drag the boarder.

How can it be made *prettier* and more functional?

Comment: Should have mentioned this is on Centos 6 with gtk-2.0. (I'm supporting an old system.)

Comment: You should have mentioned that, yes. Current GNOME versions use a completely different window manager from what CentOS 6 had, as well as a different settings system and even different appearance.

Comment: sheepishly ... I had tagged it with gnome to start.

Comment: Maybe it is just me ... but we have gobs of screen space (none of my machines have less than 2k, and they go up from there) on any newer machine, and even in older machines a border of 3 or 4 pixels never hurt. Even the raspberry pi I have has a decent size screen. Why would anyone want to make a visual control not *visible* on the screen? sigh.

Comment: Okay, now I see why nobody will care. I've been on CentOS 6 instead of 7 for a while and it isn't a problem on 7. :( 

I'll figure out what the difference is and then post it back here when I figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the keyboard+mouse to resize by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>
with a middle-click (or right-click in some environments)
anywhere on the window, then drag to resize.

Comment: Middle click and keyboard using a laptop? or with a mouse that has no middle button? lol I have both those situations all the time (I use a ton of different systems).

Comment: That is an alternate for some, but what about direct answer to the question? It used to be possible, and is far superior for most users to have a visual means of doing things than having a hidden means.

Comment: Usually the border is also clickable around it, so it's virtually extended no matter how thin it is. Isn't this so in your case?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be. It actually changes the mouse cursor over a larger area than what it works (i.e., it might display the resize arrow/bar, but if you click, it selects anything but resize).

Comment: Is this the case with all windows or just some?

Comment: It is the same with all the windows.

Comment: Might it have something to do with your theme in the [gtkrc file](https://wiki.gnome.org/Attic/GnomeArt/Tutorials/GtkThemes)? You might look for all occurrences of `border-width` in it.